# Face Detection error

Tags: android, android-camera, face-recognition, vision

I am using this library 
http://www.truiton.com/2017/05/android-face-detection-example/

When i am going to press scan face I get this error. I dont know why.
scan failed: found nothing to scan 
I add the permission on my application. Bu i get error again.
I am trying a lot of thing about that but i didn't find anything.
The image is saved on my sd card too . but i got the error

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        scanResults = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.results);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.scannedResults);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            editedBitmap = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(SAVED_INSTANCE_BITMAP);
            if (savedInstanceState.getString(SAVED_INSTANCE_URI) != null) {
                imageUri = Uri.parse(savedInstanceState.getString(SAVED_INSTANCE_URI));
            }
            imageView.setImageBitmap(editedBitmap);
            scanResults.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(SAVED_INSTANCE_RESULT));
        }
        detector = new FaceDetector.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setTrackingEnabled(false)
                .setLandmarkType(FaceDetector.ALL_LANDMARKS)
                .setClassificationType(FaceDetector.ALL_CLASSIFICATIONS)
                .build();
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new
                        String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    takePicture();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Denied!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PHOTO_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            launchMediaScanIntent();
            try {
                scanFaces();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    private void scanFaces() throws Exception {
        Bitmap bitmap = decodeBitmapUri(this, imageUri);
        if (detector.isOperational() && bitmap != null) {
            editedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap
                    .getHeight(), bitmap.getConfig());
            float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            paint.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 61, 61));
            paint.setTextSize((int) (14 * scale));
            paint.setShadowLayer(1f, 0f, 1f, Color.WHITE);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(3f);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(editedBitmap);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
            Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(editedBitmap).build();
            SparseArray<Face> faces = detector.detect(frame);
            scanResults.setText(null);
            for (int index = 0; index < faces.size(); ++index) {
                Face face = faces.valueAt(index);
                canvas.drawRect(
                        face.getPosition().x,
                        face.getPosition().y,
                        face.getPosition().x + face.getWidth(),
                        face.getPosition().y + face.getHeight(), paint);
                scanResults.setText(scanResults.getText() + "Face " + (index + 1) + "\n");
                scanResults.setText(scanResults.getText() + "Smile probability:" + "\n");
                scanResults.setText(scanResults.getText() + String.valueOf(face.getIsSmilingProbability()) + "\n");
                scanResults.setText(scanResults.getText() + "Left Eye Open Probability: " + "\n");
                scanResults.setText(scanResults.getText() + String.valueOf(face.getIsLeftEyeOpenProbability()) + "\n");
                scanResults.setText(scanResults.getText() + "Right Eye Open Probability: " + "\n");
                scanResults.setText(scanResults.getText() + String.valueOf(face.getIsRightEyeOpenProbability()) + "\n");
                scanResults.setText(scanResults.getText() + "---------" + "\n");

                for (Landmark landmark : face.getLandmarks()) {
                    int cx = (int) (landmark.getPosition().x);
                    int cy = (int) (landmark.getPosition().y);
                    canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, 5, paint);
                }
            }

            if (faces.size() == 0) {
                scanResults.setText("Scan Failed: Found nothing to scan");
            } else {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(editedBitmap);
                scanResults.setText(scanResults.getText() + "No of Faces Detected: " + "\n");
                scanResults.setText(scanResults.getText() + String.valueOf(faces.size()) + "\n");
                scanResults.setText(scanResults.getText() + "---------" + "\n");
            }
        } else {
            scanResults.setText("Could not set up the detector!");
        }
    }

    private void takePicture() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "picture.jpg");
        imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", photo);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        if (imageUri != null) {
            outState.putParcelable(SAVED_INSTANCE_BITMAP, editedBitmap);
            outState.putString(SAVED_INSTANCE_URI, imageUri.toString());
            outState.putString(SAVED_INSTANCE_RESULT, scanResults.getText().toString());
        }
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        detector.release();
    }

    private void launchMediaScanIntent() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(imageUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }

    private Bitmap decodeBitmapUri(Context ctx, Uri uri) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int targetW = 600;
        int targetH = 600;
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ctx.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), null, bmOptions);
        int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
        int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

        int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetH);
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;

        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ctx.getContentResolver()
                .openInputStream(uri), null, bmOptions);
    }
```

Comment: Use this : https://developers.google.com/vision/android/face-tracker-tutorial

Comment: please paste your logcat